# Calculating a number which is incremented to get a new total

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a character generator that should calculate your score based on how much experience points you have allocated to it.  To get a score of 1, you need 1 xp, score of 2 is 3XP, 3 is 6XP, 4 is 10XP, 5 is 15XP, etc.

I am struggling with what should be a basic way to determine that if I have 10XP in a skill, the score is 4.  Or if I have 105XP in it, the skill should be 14.

There is a multiplier of 1.5 which should allow you to buy a skill for less than the default XP.  For example, instead of needing 3 points for a score of 2, you need 2.  Or to get 6, you only need 4.

Oddly enough this code mostly works until I get to values greater than 10.  Then it seems to exponentially need a lot more points than expected.

The user would click on an input and type/increment the number, which fires the following:

```
getScoreFromXP(xp) {
 const xpMultiplier: number = 1.5
 const calcXP: number = xp * xpMultiplier;
 return this.getScoreFromXPCalc(calcXP);
}

getScoreFromXPCalc(xp) {
 let val: number = 0;
  while (xp > val) {
   val++;
   xp = xp - val;
  }
 return val;
}
```

How can I do this calculation better so it actually works as intended?

Comment: If you change the condition of the `while` to `xp >= val + 1` it will work with non-integers too. Alternatively, you can use the formula `xp = val * (val - 1)/2` for the sum of the first `val` integers https://tsplay.dev/WkOOpW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you kikon, your answer worked wonderfully!

I ended up using `xp = val * (val - 1)/2` and it calculated as intended.